# Removing comments in a block of text whilst editing

Tags: comments

I am editing two files on Overleaf where I essentially need to "split" text across. My current workflow is to comment out lines that I want to move to the second document (on the first document) and then I can copy paste the block of text. Then I remove the uncommented lines (as they are the ones that need to appear on the first document) and then re-uncommenting the commented lines (to now appear on the second document). This process isn't extremely slow or anything, but it would be a lot faster if there was a method for simply removing any uncommented lines of text in a selection. Then I implement the same workflow extremely quickly.

Is there a way to remove any uncommented lines in a block of text? In other words (I only want fully commented lines to be kept). For example

Example:

```
This is line one %with a comment.
% This line is entirely commented.
This line two %%%%% with comments. 
% %%This line is commented. 
This line isn't commented.
```

In an ideal world, I would want to highlight all this text, and press a button to obtain

```
This is line one %with a comment.
This line two %%%%% with comments. 
This line isn't commented.
```

I'm aware how I might implement a script that would perform this across a whole document, but the key is that I want to have the ability to do this very quickly -- preferably only by using a keyboard shortcut. Additionally, only for a selected region of text?

I am very new to text-editing, so I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Questions that are specific to the Overleaf platform should be addressed to the Overleaf Help Desk. Their LaTeX support staff are top-notch.

Comment: do search and replace (ctrl-h), then activate the RegExp option (bottom left button looking like `.*`), then replace `^%.*` with nothing (this expression means `^` start of line `%` literal percent sign `.*` anything after that until the end of the line). There is also a button to search/replace only within the selection. Within Overleaf I don't see an easy option to remove the resulting empty lines though.

Comment: If you search for `^%.*\n` (`\n` matches the line break as well), that will replace the entire line.